# Excess elements in union initializer. C

Tags: c, union

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

union IFC {
    int i;
    float f;
    char c;
};

int main(void) {
    union IFC ifc = {5, 3.14, 'A'};
    printf("Union is -\ninteger: %d;\nfloat: %.2f;\ncharacter: %c;\n", ifc.i, ifc.f, ifc.c);
    return 0;
}
```

Редактор кода подчёркивает в 11 строке `3.14`. При наведении курсора всплывает подсказка: "Excess elements in union initializer." У меня union должен принимать 3 переменные, а сообщает о избытке переменных уже на второй. Что не так?

Если скомпилировать и выполнить, то вывод будет таким:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сначала вы сами объясните, чего именно вы пытаетесь добиться, указывая сразу три инициализатора для `union`. Какой в этом смысл?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что значит "у меня union должен принимать 3 переменные"?

В `union` не бывает трех переменных одновременно. В `union` живет только *одно* поле в каждый момент времени и инициализировать вы можете только *одно* поле, по вашему выбору. Инициализатор без тега будет относиться к *первому* полю вашего `union`. Хотите создать `union` с другим активным полем - используйте тэги при инициализации

```
union IFC ifc = { .f = 3.14 };
```

Но в любом случае инициализировать вы можете только одно поле `union`.